# MySQL: Alter table to create partition giving primary key error

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I need to partition my MySQL table using LIST COLUMNS partition. I already have the table with data so I need to alter the table to create the partition.

Here is what I am doing.

Sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id bigint(20) primary key auto_increment,
  .....
  status varchar(10)
);
```

Alter table script that I am using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (status) 
( 
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (NULL), 
    PARTITION p2 VALUES IN ('SUCCESS'), 
    PARTITION p3 VALUES IN ('FAILED')
);
```

**Error: A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function**

However, when I just tried to create a table without id column as below:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  status varchar(10)
);
```

And then try to create the partition using the same above alter script, it worked. So, am I missing anything on the table with id?

**SQLFiddle:**

Working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8a3d1

Not Working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d06a1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found the solution. I had to change the primary key. The primary key should include both the id and the status column for partitioning based on the status.